# C# finding and replacing attributes XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an output XML file with the following structure

```
<OFBM time="10:32" date="06.10.2017" saveName="Unnamed save">
<folder name="file:///C:/Users/AD/Downloads" />
<folder name="file:///C:/Users/AD/Desktop/t" />
<folder name="file:///C:/ProgramData/OFBM" />
</OFBM>
```

date and time combination are unique. How based on time, and date, I can parse a value that will change the saveName attribute?
What's the best way of doing it?

This is what I wrote up

```
    public void saveNames(string time, string date, string folderName)
    {
    if(folderName == "Unnamed save")
    return;
    XElement root = XElement.Load(pathToXml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> address =
            from el in root.Elements("OFBM")
            where (string)el.Attribute("time") == time
            where (string)el.Attribute("date") == date
            select el;
        foreach (XElement el in address.Elements("saveName"))
        {
            el.ReplaceWith(folderName);

        }
        root.Save(pathToXml);

    }
```

Also tried this

```
            //  <OFBM time="10:30" date="06.10.2017" saveName="Unnamed save">
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(pathToXml);
        //The XPathNavigator object is used for read-only XPath queries. The XPath queries may return a resulting value or many nodes
        XPathNavigator documentNav = document.CreateNavigator();
        // This expression uses standard XPath syntax.
        string filter = "@*";
        XPathNodeIterator NodeIter = documentNav.Select(filter);
        while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Save: {0}", NodeIter.Current.Value);
        };
```

PS. My code changes nothing, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only the Xml Snippet (like in your example) you can use this code:

```
if (root.Attribute("time").Value == time && 
    root.Attribute("date").Value == date &&
    root.Attribute("saveName") != null)
{
    root.Attribute("saveName").Value = folderName;
}
```

`root` is your **OFBM** Element ... therefore `root.Element("OFBM")` is null

EDIT:

If you have a xml with several **OFBM** elements (i think you have more than one). Use this:

```
var address = root.Elements("OFBM").Where(element =>
    element.Attribute("time").Value == time &&
    element.Attribute("date").Value == date &&
    element.Attribute("saveName") != null);

foreach (XElement el in address)
{
    el.Attribute("saveName").Value = folderName;
}
```

Xml Example:

```
<root>
  <OFBM time="10:32" date="06.10.2017" saveName="Unnamed save">
   <folder name="file:///C:/Users/AD/Downloads" />
   <folder name="file:///C:/Users/AD/Desktop/t" />
   <folder name="file:///C:/ProgramData/OFBM" />
  </OFBM>
  <OFBM time="10:42" date="06.10.2017" saveName="Unnamed save">
   <folder name="file:///C:/Users/AD/Downloads" />
   <folder name="file:///C:/Users/AD/Desktop/t" />
   <folder name="file:///C:/ProgramData/OFBM" />
  </OFBM>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(pathToXml);
```

Here, `root` *is* `OFBM`. So when you query `root.Elements()`, the elements returned will be the children of `OFBM`, i.e. 3 `folder` elements. This means your query `root.Elements("OFBM")` will never return any elements.

Secondly, `ReplaceWith` will replace the entire element with some text. You want to set the `saveName` attribute value.

This code would work:

```
var root = XElement.Load("path/to/file.xml");

if ((string) root.Attribute("time") == "10:32" && 
    (string) root.Attribute("date") == "06.10.2017")
{
    root.SetAttributeValue("saveName", "new folder name");
}

root.Save("path/to/file.xml");
```

Comment: For some reason the root.Attribute("time") is empty. Any idea why? While debugging I see that root isn't empty. Root has: -  root {<root saveName="Test4">
  <OFBM time="10:20" date="06.10.2017" saveName="Unnamed save">

Comment: Okay, noticed that OFBM isn't the root element it's a child of it, so I need to change the attribute of a child :D

Comment: @AleksD in which case, the XML in your question is not representative of your problem.

Comment: Totally my fault for misrepresenting the actual XML file. Sorry.

Comment: @AleksD no problem, seems you've got it sorted now at least!